# C dereferencing a pointer warning, even thought they are both chars

Tags: c, pointers, stdin, fgets

I have some code that gets input from `stdin` via `fgets`.

I need to detect when the user gives no input, because that will break my other code.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char input[100];
  char first;
  printf("Input something:\n>\n");
  first = (char)(&fgets(input, 100, stdin)[0]);
  if(first == "\n"){
    // handle empty input here...
  }
}
```

The problem is that it gives me a warning:

```
main.c:6:10: warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
first = (char)(&fgets(name1point, 100, stdin)[0]);
        ^
```

Except that `first` and the first char of `fgets` are both char type.

If I just do

```
if(fgets(input, 100, stdin)[0] == "\n"){
```

then it gives me a warning:

```
main.c:7:12: warning: comparison between pointer and integer
  if(first == "\n"){
           ^~
```

So then I need to dereference it.

Can anyone help me? I am a beginner.

Comment: `"\n"` is a `char *`. You need to use `strcmp`. Alternatively, you can compare `first == '\n'`

Comment: That was a typo.

Comment: `fgets` returns `char *`. When you do `&fgets` it tries to produce `char **`, so leave off the `&`. You probably want `char *str = fgets(...)` and `if (str[0] == '\n')`

Comment: Thanks! That was what I needed!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A couple of things:

- fgets() returns a char *, so &fgets() is a char**, so &fgets()[0] is
  a char*, so (to avoid pouring over the yacc grammar for C to figure
  out the syntactic ins and out of unary and postfix expressions
  (although it is interesting)), just delete the '&'.
- in the comparison if(first == "\n"), first is a char, so make it
  if(first == '\n')

So ...

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void){
  char input[100];
  char first;
  printf("Input something:\n>\n");
#if 0
  first = (char)(&fgets(input, 100, stdin)[0]);
  if(first == "\n"){
    // handle empty input here...
  }
#else
  first = (char)(fgets(input, 100, stdin)[0]);
  if(first == '\n'){
    // handle empty input here...
  }
#endif
}
```